# Properties of Expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

I'm trying to get more familiar with $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$, and all examples that I have come across seems to satisfy this expression. My question then is, if there exist an example of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ for which $E(XY) \neq E(X)E(Y)$?

I am looking for an example using a joint probability distribution table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\operatorname EX=0$, $\operatorname EX^2=1$ and $X=Y$. Then
$$
1=\operatorname EX^2=\operatorname E[XY]\ne\operatorname EX\operatorname EY=\operatorname EX\operatorname EX=0.
$$

Comment: For clarity, one could take $X$ to be the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$, i.e. $\mathrm{N}(0,1)$. Nice answer. (+1)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one question, can this example be translated into a joint probability distribution table? So I could calculate $E(XY)$ and $E(X)E(Y)$ from that table. The reason I'm asking is because I am trying to show that $E(XY) \neq E(X)E(Y)$ from a joint probability distribution table.

Comment: @MadsJohansen In my example, we basically have just one random variable. If you want a particular example, consider a random variable $X$ such that $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=1/2$. Since $Y=X$, we also have that $P(Y=-1)=P(Y=1)=1/2$.